# Texture in Point Primitive

Tags: ios, swift, metal, metalkit

I am using point method to draw Squares.

```
commandEncoder.drawPrimitives(type: .point, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount:1 )
```

With this one I am Passing a Texture of Screen Size.(Drawable Size). I can draw as below in the shader.

```
fragment half4 fragment_chalk(VertexOutChalk params[[stage_in]],
                               texture2d<half>texture4 [[texture(0)]],
                              float2 texcoord [[ point_coord ]]
                              )
{

    constexpr sampler defaultSampler;
    half4 alphaSample = texture4.sample(defaultSampler,texcoord) *half4(0.8666667, 0.101960786, 0.35686275,0.7);
    return alphaSample;

}
```

But My need is to Not to Draw Full texture. I want to draw the Part Corresponding to the Particular Square. For Texture Sampling I need to Pass coordinates relevant to Screen.I want to change the coordinate for Sampling. How can I do that

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Particular Square is in **normalized** coordinates and in the same format as `NSRect` (`origin.x`, `origin.y`, `size.width`, `size.height`), then you would want to pass this in with `params`, and modify `texcoord` like this:

```
texcoord = texcoord * params.PartSquare.size
     + FullTextureSize * params.PartSquare.origin;
```